# Confluence macro for specifying a reference, source of the quotation, etc.?

Tags: confluence

Is there a way in Confluence for specifying a reference to a text passage — for example, to provide the source of the quoted text, in a similar way as is done on Wikipedia, so that it's rendered like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<sup>1</sup>

[down the page]

---

<sup>1</sup> Cicero

Ideally, the subscript "1" should be an internal hyperlink

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this plugin may help: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.adaptavist.confluence.footnotes

> The footnotes plugin allows you to quickly and easily add footnote
>   references to your wiki pages.
>
> You can:
>
> - Define Footnotes - Define any number of footnotes throughout your content
> - Display Footnotes - Display a table of footnotes anywhere in the page
> - Quickly move between content and footnotes with a click of the mouse

Comment: Great answer. You could also just use anchor tags & links, but that is less elegant than Aziz's answer.

Comment: Great answer, but: this plugin is currently only available for Confluence 4.x, Confluence is now on 5.4.3. So there are chances that this will not work for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using [anchors](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/anchors-139442.html):

Pros:

- It is native in Confluence

Cons:

- It is a very manual procedure (no automatic numbering, etc.)

Comment: Broken link, I think the new link would be https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/anchors-139442.html